# Compress web files without losing its readability?

Tags: web, compression

Can you compress all the web files like html, css, js, php without losing its readability?

I'm developing a dynamic website, but then client require me to update the site quite frequently, the problem is that whenever I make any changes to the website, I need to backup a .min version(to webhost) and the original files(for development).

The problem is that keeping two sets of files are quite tedious, and prone to error easily.....

Is there a better way like a javascript that will handle all the compress functions when upload to host and I can re-use the same files for developement?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's separate compression and minification. I assume we are only talking about minification here (removing spaces etc.) not compression like gzip.

There's 2 common ways to serve minified css/js/etc.

1. Edit readable version, minify offline, upload the minified files.
2. Edit and upload readable files, but dynamically serve a minified version to users.

I agree #1 is more tedious and prone to error, if sometimes you are forced to make changes to the min version and forget to bring the changes back to your dev side.

There're a lot of ways to achieve #2. If you're using PHP I would suggest [Minify](https://code.google.com/p/minify/) (it not only minifies but joins and compresses your CSS/JS to reduce file requests as well). That way you can maintain 1 set of readable CSS/JS files on both your dev and production side, and let Minify take care of the rest.

Comment: My bet on the terminology, and thanks for the head up, I know what to do now :)